# Android ConstraintLayout Overlapping issue

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I'm currently playing with the ConstraintLayout, what an awesome tools!
But... there is obviously a but...

This layout correspond to a childrenView layout inside an expandableListView.
The problem happen when i have long text, like this one.
We can see the chipcloup going over the text while the constraint indicate that it shouldn't be.

[image: ConstraintLayout Overlap]

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView_experience_resume"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView_experience_roleResume"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/textView_experience_resume" />

    <com.yarolegovich.discretescrollview.DiscreteScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView_experience_imagesView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
        app:dsv_orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/textView_experience_roleResume" />


    <com.google.android.flexbox.FlexboxLayout
        android:id="@+id/flexboxLayout_experience_chipContainer"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"


        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:alignContent="space_around"

        app:alignItems="flex_start"
        app:flexWrap="wrap"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/scrollView_experience_imagesView"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.508"
        app:showDivider="middle"
        tools:ignore="UselessLeaf">

    </com.google.android.flexbox.FlexboxLayout>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image: BluePrint]

In that case the DiscreteScrollView has a GONE visibility, but even when it's visible, the chipcloud also goes in front of the DiscreteScrollView.